# Add Code to .js File by the Click of a Form Button

Tags: javascript, html

I want my form to add this code replaced with info provided in the form filled out by the user everytime the Submit button is pressed.

```
{
    flag = false;

    username = new Array("alex364981");
    password = new Array("Codylewis");
    page = "admin/admin242f1221r2fd2fd12r" + ".html";

    if (form.username.value == username[0] && form.password.value == password[0])

    {
        self.location.href = page;
        flag = true;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any other information? I'm not really clear on what your problem is.

Comment: I want the HTML form to add that code to the login.js file everytime the Submit button is pressed replaced with the info provided in the form

Comment: You cannot add text to a JavaScript file on the disk.

Comment: Why do you want to ADD code to a file??? Why not _execute_ it?

Comment: What does execute mean? Sorry, I've only been a web designer for a year

Comment: @Marcell I need it to add the code so that when the user goes to login after registration they can

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but for sure, storing user input the in any `.js` file is a very bad practice. Not to mention that you cannot access anything on local filesystem via JS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're trying to implement a simple authentication system using JavaScript (i.e., client-side code). This is not a good idea.

One big issue here is that, as other commenters have pointed out, you can't write to a .js file on your server from the client side. You would need to do something on the server side in order to make this happen.

But there are two really big security flaws to this plan otherwise: First, a valid username and password are provided to the user in plain text. View source, and there's your username and password. Second, the authentication is merely placed on the redirect to the secured page. If you know the URL to the page—which can also be obtained by simply viewing source—you can just go straight to the page and avoid the authentication in the first place.

The only way you can provide an authentication mechanism with any form of security at all is to use a server-side language like PHP, Python, Ruby, or ASP.NET (or [server-side JavaScript](http://nodejs.org), but that's another story). **You cannot implement a reasonable authentication mechanism through simple client-side JavaScript.**